# Copy components to a different project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to copy a lot of graphic controls (user controls, button, labels etc.) from an old project to a new one. The components are all placed on a tab in a tabcontrol on the main form.

It is the same issue that is discussed below, but the problem is that I need to copy the components to a different project (running in another instance of Visual Studio)

[Copying control components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317069/copying-control-components)

Question:
How can I do this, as it seems like copy/paste of components between projects is not possible?

Info:
I know I could copy/paste the lines from the designer file (even though this is not recommended), but we are talking about too many controls which code lines I would have to sort out from the messy designer file (the relevant lines are split up all over the file).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be possible to copy "standard" controls such as Button, Label etc. directly between projects, but not e.g. custom user controls.

I ended up creating a new form with a tabcontrol in the old project, and then I copied the graphics to this new clean form (copy inside the same project was no problem).

The new form in the old project then contained all the graphics I wanted to move to the new project (and nothing else).

I then copied the files of the form and added the new form from the old project to the new project, and then I could easily move the graphics to the right place in the new project.

Hope everyone understood, if not just ask!